# How can I show up to 2 decimal places without rounding off?

Tags: java, android, math

I want to take two decimal places only for a float without rounding off. eg. 4.21777 should be 4.21 and not 4.22. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you planning on using that value for more math, or just for displaying to the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple answer:

```
double x = 4.21777;
double y = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: what if value is 1.2 one decimal

Comment: @KhalidSaeed x = 1.2
y = Math.floor(120/100) => Math.floor(1.2) => 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Subtract `0.005` and then round. For example if you just want to print the number you can use a format of `%f6.2` and the value `x-0.005`.

Answer (score 1):

```
float f = 4.21777 * 100;
int solution = (int)f;
f = solution/100;
```

This should work ;)

Explanation: By multiplying with 100, you will get 421.777, which, castet to int, is being rounded down to 421. Now divided by 100 returns its actual value.